# Xamarin.Forms: DocumentNode.Descendants return null at Android device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, html-agility-pack

I using Xamarin.Forms with HTML Agility Pack to parse my HTML. At Windows UWP it working and I get a node with 'a', with Android target I get null result.

My target is to get the name of the video file.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "mediafallbacklink");
```

**doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().First() is null too.**

Is the HTML with the Android device the problem? And if it is so, why?

```html
<div class="no-overflow"><p><p>This is a test.</p><p><span class="mediaplugin mediaplugin_qt">
    <object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="400" height="315">
        <param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
        <param name="src" value="video_2016-06-24_19-12-25.mov">
        <param name="controller" value="true">
        <param name="loop" value="false">
        <param name="autoplay" value="false">
        <param name="autostart" value="false">
        <param name="scale" value="aspect">
        <!--[if !IE]><!-->
        <object data="video_2016-06-24_19-12-25.mov" type="video/quicktime" width="400" height="315">
            <param name="src" value="video_2016-06-24_19-12-25.mov">
            <param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
            <param name="controller" value="true">
            <param name="loop" value="false">
            <param name="autoplay" value="false">
            <param name="autostart" value="false">
            <param name="scale" value="aspect">
        <!--<![endif]-->
            <a class="mediafallbacklink" href="video_2016-06-24_19-12-25.mov">video_2016-06-24_19-12-25.mov</a>
        <!--[if !IE]><!-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</span><br></p><br><p></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, 'var nodes' is with debug on Android device always null, but the data is there. All is working correctly.